# JavaScript: Calculating a sum from values found in a HTML table

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```js
<script>
   
    function calculateSum() {
 
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
 
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

```html
<table id="payout12" class="display" style="float:left; width: 100%;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px #666666;-moz-box-sizing: none;" border=1  data="${payout}" border="1">
        
        <thead>
<h2>Discount</h2>    
        <td class="heading">Charge</td>
        <td class="heading">Cost Before Discount</td>
        <td class="heading">After Plan Discount</td>
        <td class="heading">After Booking Discount</td>
        
     
       </tr> 
     </thead>
     <tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${payouts}" var="payout" varStatus="row">
       <tr>
            <td>Base Cost</td> 
            <td> ${payout.baseCost.costBeforeDiscount}</td>
            <td>${payout.baseCost.afterPlanDiscount}</td>
            <td>${payout.baseCost.afterBookingDiscount}</td>
            
       </tr>
              <c:forEach items="${payouts}" var="payout" >
       <tr>
            <td>Other Charges</td> 
            <td>${payout.otherCharges.costBeforeDiscount1}</td>
            <td>${payout.otherCharges.afterPlanDiscount1}</td>
            <td>${payout.otherCharges.afterBookingDiscount1}</td>
            
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

I had a table with 3 columns and 4 rows in website view. I need to add the column values and show at the bottom of the table as total. I'm using spring mvc3. How can I calculate the sum in JSP?

but this code i got in net. and it's input type is "text". and my requirement is to add the values of a column retrieved from db to the table

table looks like

```html
<script>
   
    function calculateSum() {
 
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
 
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

charge               costBbeforeDiscount    costAfterDiscount
base cost              123546                   111112
othert charges         114523                   104523

Comment: What have you tried? The short answer is use the `+` operator, but it seems like that's not where you're having trouble.  Post some code and give us an idea of where you're struggling.

Comment: Show what you tried?

Comment: <script>
   
    function calculateSum() {
 
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function() {
 
            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
 
        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>

Comment: i tried it but nothing is happening... i don't know how to get the total sum at the bottom ... worried

Comment: @user3599302 Please paste your code in question not here

Comment: i got this in internet...but it is doing the input type "text". but i need to calculate the retrieved values from db to the table. if you have any suggestion most welcome

Comment: @user3599302 please paste your Jsp code

Comment: @user3599302: I think you're mixing up a few things: You keep mentioning JSP and Spring. These are *Java* technologies. Your code uses jQuery, which is a *JavaScript* framework. Java and JavaScript are two completely different things.

Comment: wait i'll add all my code

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary code. You don't need to add your server-side code, as it's irrelevant to the question. I would ask/recommend to restore my previous edit (use the “rollback” feature), or have at least a look at the improvements. Simply add the *generated* HTML to that revision, and you should be fine.

Comment: am new to this forum and i dont know how to use this ...:(